# Building minimal standalone executable with GCC

Tags: gcc, compilation

I have few programs (written in C) implementing some algorithms, that I use to measure computation time. Whole data is implemented as static libraries directly in code, there's no input and output from these programs. There's also no C library calls (no printfs etc.).

I want to build fully independent and minimal executable. I don't want to link my program with libgcc (target CPU has coprocessor, so I don't need to emulate floating point arithmetic), C library or any other. Actually I want to make my program as independent as it's possible. On Linux ELF program has to be linked only with crt0.o to run properly, right?

I'm mostly asking because I'm curious ;)

Answer (score 3):

Link with `gcc -nostdlib`, then use `objdump -h` and `strip --remove-section=...` to really make it small by getting rid of silly things like the comment section and the exception handling frame information sections. Keep removing sections until it stops working.

And compile with `-Os` of course