# How is it possible to generate minimal Elf64 executable file in linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

I want to know what is the minimum size of an Elf64 executable.
for that purpose I compiled the following code:

```
cat main.c 
int _start(){}
```

with this command:

`gcc -s -nostdlib main.c`

and then removed some sections in executable with: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11976684/10641441)

```
strip --remove-section=.comment a.out 
strip --remove-section=.gnu.hash a.out 
strip --remove-section=.note.gnu.build-id a.out
```

I know that running ./a.out causes segfault but this is not a problem since a.out is a valid Elf64 binary.

now:

```
du -b a.out 
4752    a.out
```

Is it possible to shrink it further or make an Elf64 binary with smaller size with another method?

Comment: What you are asking is "tiny elf", you may search for that. Also there are "tiny pe" corresponding in Windows. They all write in assembly language.

Comment: Something like https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html